# How to apply Task Async Pattern and WCF's ChannelFactory<TChannel>?

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, task, channelfactory

We have a robust WCF client built in 2008 on .NET 3.5 (now recompiled under .NET 4.0) that talks to our own WCF service over the net.tcp binding.  The robust client uses ChannelFactory<IOurServiceInterface>() to generate a service proxy, through which we currently make synchronous calls to the service.  We get results back from each call; we have no one-way calls.

We are migrating to .NET 4.5 / C# 5 and would like to make the client asynchronous using async / await / TAP.  How best to do this in a way that results in clean code, and good runtime performance?

(I've looked at MS documentation on this subject, but it always talks about running svcutil.  We don't use svcutil; we use ChannelFactory directly.  Also: MS documentation for calling operations asynchronously using a channel factory under .NET 4.5 are unchanged since .NET 3.0 days.  Seems ChannelFactory hasn't embraced the new asynchrony.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap existing APM (`Begin*`/`End*`) endpoints into TAP-ready `Task`s using [`TaskFactory.FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx).

You may find my [Async WCF Today and Tomorrow post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html) helpful, which shows how to use TAP with the pre-VS2012 svcutil.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  After searching for info based on your answer, and after reading your post, I think that this is the best that can be done.  I'm surprised that ChannelFactory in this day and age still expects you to use the APM pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095247/async-ctp-how-can-i-use-async-await-to-call-a-wcf-service/10020063#10020063) ?
I made an example of an awaitable `[OperationContract]` returning `Task<TResponse>`.