# Proper way to implement a synchronous queue of requests while using async/await

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm wondering if someone could guide me in the right direction for creating a synchronous queue of requests to a server that requires this pattern.

I would like to keep using the already implemented async/await pattern in my code and also be able to enqueue both GET and POST requests that are generic in both upload parameters as well as downloaded result (which will be serialized with JSON).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain what you want in more detail? Why do you need a synchronous queue? What does it mean to “keep using the already implemented async/await pattern”?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [`ActionBlock<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx) from the [TPL Dataflow library](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow).

Alternatively, you could use [`AsyncProducerConsumerQueue`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncProducerConsumerQueue) from my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your client code may be async while your service is purely synchronous.
You may set ServiceBehaviorAttribute so your service performs one request after the other.
It even can run on the same thread that you used to open the servicehost.
If your service never executes an 'await' it runs synchronous. Using this design you can enhance your service when needed without breaking the client.
See [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095247/async-ctp-how-can-i-use-async-await-to-call-a-wcf-service/10020063#10020063) for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a lock if you require single-threaded access. There is an async equivalent for this: `AsyncLock` (or `AsyncSemaphore`).

No need for complex constructs like queues or data-flow. (`AsyncSemaphore` has one such queue under the hood, but that doesn't matter to you).